# String array index error

Tags: android, arrays

I use the following method, but every time i use it i got error.
I cant figure out why because i perfrom this checking

`if(unWanted == null || unWanted[0] == null)`

The error is in this code:

```
unWanted[0] == null
```

but if i do only

```
 if(unWanted == null)
```

It doest not see unWaned as null.

Thank for helping :)

the error code:

```
05-12 06:24:41.293: E/AndroidRuntime(24373): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.workoutlog/com.example.workoutlog.AddWorkOutPage}: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=0; index=0
```

My method:

```
public void checking(){

        DataBaseMain data = new DataBaseMain(this);
        data.open();
        String[] unWanted = data.getAllUnwantedExercies();  
        data.close();

        if(unWanted == null || unWanted[0] == null)
                    Toast.makeText(this, "good", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            else
        Toast.makeText(this, "bad", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

The method to get the String array from my DB.

```
   public String[] getAllUnwantedExercies() {

        Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(true, TABLE_NAME, new String[] {COLUMN_NOT_ON_LIST_EXERCISE}, null, null, COLUMN_NOT_ON_LIST_EXERCISE, null, null, null);

        int dayExercise = c.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NOT_ON_LIST_EXERCISE);

        if(c.getCount() < 1)
            return null;

        int f = 0;

        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){

            if(c.getString(dayExercise) != null && c.getString(dayExercise).equals("") == false)
                f++;
        }

        String[] list = new String[f];

        int j = 0;
        for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()){
            if(c.getString(dayExercise) != null && c.getString(dayExercise).equals("") == false){
            list[j] = c.getString(dayExercise);
            j++;
            }
        }

        return list;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
unWanted[0] == null
```

It's clear that your array has no values in it. Attempting to reference the first index of an array of length 0, as explained in your stack trace, is a run time error.

```
unWanted == null
```

This doesn't work because the array object itself is not null.

**A work around**

A simple solution here is, at the end of your function, check the length of the array. If it is 0, you know it has no values, and you can return null.

```
if(list.length == 0)
{
    return null;
}
else
{
    return list;
}
```

or more concisely:

```
return list.length == 0? null:list;
```

Then when you get your array back from your function, all you need to do is test to check if the array is null.

```
if(unWanted == null)
{
    // Array is empty.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just change this line:

```
if(unWanted == null || unWanted[0] == null)
```

By this one:

```
if(unWanted.length <= 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
unWanted[0] == null
```

Here you are trying to check the first position of your array is `null` or not. Instead of this check your array size is `0` or not.

```
if(unWanted.length==0){
   // your code
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check that the `length` is greater than 0. It is not `null` because you are returning a `list` albeit an empty `list`. So it isn't `null` but also doesn't have a `length`

Answer (score 0):

`unWanted` is not `null` does not mean you can reference it is first element by using `unWanter[0]` because it might be an empty array.